# Why are areas of my face lit by blue light removed when my keying color is green?

Tags: compositing-nodes, movie-clip-editor

I am trying to remove a green screen using the Keying Node. When choose green as my keying color, for some reason it is cutting out blue-lit sections of my face (as well as blue-lit edges of my chair).
I have no idea why this is happening, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Without Keying node:
[image]

With Keying node:
[image]

Comment: The _Key Color_ I can see in the screenshot... did you sample that from somewhere or is it just some random green you chose? Because when I use that as color selection in Photoshop for example, almost nothing of the green screen is selected: [key color sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACBK9.jpg). Whereas when I'm sampling colors in the background, a lot is selected and but not the color in the node: [background color sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhBSG.jpg). Of course you can increase the tolerance range, but the more tolerant the more unwanted parts are keyed out.

Comment: Apart from maybe the color not being perfect, the "blue" light on your face is actually bright cyan, and cyan in RGB colors is created by green and blue. So if you have a broad range of greens keyed out to get rid of the screen behind you, green from the cyan on your face gets taken away as well. Apart from that, it would really helped if your green screen was smoother, brighter and escpecially more evenly lit over its complete size.

Comment: I will change my key color to be sampled from the background. How would I increase or decrease the tolerance of key color?

Comment: There are so many tips and tricks for green screen removal... probably you should watch some tutorials that can give more in-depth explanations what all these settings mean (I usually do video editing in other software than Blender), but I guess after picking the correct color (again though, it would help a lot if the green screen was better illuminated, smoother and more uniform in color and brightness) I would most of of all try tweaking the _Screen Balance_, _Clip Black_ and _Clip White_ values. Maybe look at the _Matte_ output rather than the image first to see how it affects the mask.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will spend extra time adjusting my green screen in the future to remove as much creases and shadows as possible.